# Different results of different, but equal math operations on float in Java

Tags: java, datetime, precision, date-arithmetic, date-difference

Question about Java math operations on `float` and `int` data types.

I have to calculate the date difference in years between two dates.

The code:

```java
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Object date = obj.getInfoItem().getInfoValue();
 
Date today = new Date();
Date birthDate = null;
float dateDiff;
int age0, age1;
 
try {
    // unify the date format
    birthDate = format.parse(date.toString());
    today = format.parse(format.format(today));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
 
// calculate the age in years with round    
dateDiff = today.getTime() - birthDate.getTime();
age0     = (int)((dateDiff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) / 365);
age1     = (int)(dateDiff / (365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

Since the date difference in Java is calculated in milliseconds, thus we have to do some housekeeping work after calculation and convert received result from milliseconds to years.

After code execution, I got the following results in debugger:

```
dateDiff = 8.4896639E11  
age0 = 26  
age1 = 577
```

`age0` is a correct result.

Since both operations on `age0` and `age1` are mathematically equal, why outcomes are different?
Why there is a difference between operations «`(float / (a\*b\*c)) / d`» and «`(float / (a\*b\*c\*d))`», where `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` are `int`.

Comment: This 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 is integer overflow.

Comment: To expand on that, if you want to do calculations in floats using constant values, you should have the constants explicitly set as floats. ie. `365f * 24f * 60f * 60f * 1000f`.

Comment: «365f * 24f * 60f * 60f * 1000f» fixed the issue.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Sotirios' comment: The integer literals `365`, `24`, `60`, and `1000` all have type `int`.  Therefore, multiplication will be performed using the `int` type.  Since the mathematical result is 31536000000, and the largest possible `int` is 2147483648, the result overflows and the result will wrap around.  The result will thus be the `int` whose value is equivalent to 31536000000 modulo 2<sup>32</sup>, which is 1471228928.  Only then is it converted to a `float` to be divided into `dateDiff`.  Appending an `L` to the end of any of the integer literals will fix it, since now at least one of the multiplications will be performed using `long`.  But it might be clearer to change `365` to `365.0` (or `365f`).  (Actually, @Chill's suggestion to use `f` on all the constants appears best to me, although it's not really necessary.)